# Cloning a UTM virtual machine - IP address the same?

Tags: ip, utm

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to configure the IP address of cloned VMs with UTM?

When I create a new UTM VM, the IP address is different. This is fine.

When I clone an exisitng UTM VM, the IP is the same as the clone.

My question is, where do I start with configuring the clone to have it's own IP?

Note - I am using a shared network. And I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off the vm and go to its setting>network click on Random in the Mac address, switch on the vm you'll see it should have a new IP